How do you automatically resize text to fit in a text box without scaling the text box?
Ive used variables so i could export batch documents from a template, but i want every variable to fit in a bounding box. some texts are too long, some too short, i was looking for a way to automatically resize text without changing size of textbox so everything fits.
Thanks!

You'd need a script, because there is no such native functionality in Illustrator.
